# How to choose Option from option list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I want to set a value to the textfield i do this:

```
document.getElementById("some-textfield").value = "BlahBlahBlah";
```

But how to choose an option from dropdown option list:

```
<select tabindex = "11" name="b_month">
 <option value="">---</option>
 <option value="1">Jan</option>
 <option value="2">Feb</option>
 <option value="3">Mar</option>
```

I was trying something like this:

```
document.getElementByName("b_month").options[2]
```

But it doesn't work.
Again I want to change it in the website, so when i type it in console, I would see the result.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementByName` is not a function. You need to use `getElementsByName` (note the plurality), then select the appropriate element from the returned collection:

```
document.getElementsByName("b_month")[0].options[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByName("b_month")[0].selectedIndex = 2;
```